# Creating dummy variable based on value counts in a function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, dummy-variable

I'm trying to assign 0 to string that is more frequent and 1 to less frequent string in a function. My idea is that it should take any column with binary string and based on value count assign 0 and 1. How can i do that?

```
data = {'status':["Default", "Non-Default", "Non-Default", "Non-Default", "Default", "Non-Default"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

        status
    0   Default
    1   Non-Default
    2   Non-Default
    3   Non-Default
    4   Default
    5   Non-Default


    df.value_counts()

    status     
    Non-Default    4
    Default        2
    dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['binary'] = df['status'].ne(df['status'].mode().iloc[0]).astype(int)
```

`mode` gets the most frequent value, and `iloc[0]` gets the first one (in case of equality). Then we identify the values that are **NOT** this string (`True`) and convert to integer (`1`). The most frequent string will be `0`.

output:

```
        status  binary
0      Default       1
1  Non-Default       0
2  Non-Default       0
3  Non-Default       0
4      Default       1
5  Non-Default       0
```